# I am having serious issues with a php / mysqli database website that I inherited from a customer

Tags: php, mysqli, connection

The is one php file that governs rotating ads that is causing serious server performance issues and causing "too many connections" sql errors on the site.  Here is the php script.  Can anyone give me some insight into how to correct this as I am an novice at php.

```
        <?

require("../../admin/lib/config.php");
// connect to database

mysql_pconnect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
mysql_select_db(DB_NAME);

$i = 1;
function grab()
{
    $getBanner = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sponsor WHERE active='Y' AND ID != 999 AND bannerRotation = '0' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
    $banner = mysql_fetch_array($getBanner);
    if ($banner['ID'] == ''){
        mysql_query("UPDATE sponsor SET bannerRotation = '0'");
    }   
    if (file_exists(AD_PATH . $banner['ID'] . ".jpg")){
        $hasAd = 1;
    }
    if (file_exists(BANNER_PATH . $banner['ID'] . ".jpg")){
        return "$banner[ID],$hasAd";
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

while ($i <= 3){
    $banner = grab();
    if ($banner != 0){
        $banner = explode(",",$banner);
        mysql_query("UPDATE sponsor SET bannerView = bannerView + 1 WHERE ID='$banner[0]'");
        mysql_query("UPDATE sponsor SET bannerRotation = '1' WHERE ID = '$banner[0]'");
        echo "banner$i=$banner[0]&hasAd$i=$banner[1]&";
        $i++;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Even without the script, I would check the slow query log and see if there are queries that are consistently causing an issue, or running frequently. If there is a slow running query it compounds the issue the more it's run. That's a starting point, until the code is available it'll be tough to really determine.

Comment: Sorry, i think i have it posted now.

Answer (score 2):

**I see not mysqli**

The problem is that `mysql_pconnect()` opens a **persistent** connection to the database and is not closed at end of execution, and as you are not calling mysql_close() anywhere the connection never gets closed.

Its all in the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-pconnect.php

Comment: So changing it to mysql_connect() and closing the script at the bootn with mysql_close() would correct the persistent connection?  That would also, I assume, correct the "too many connections" errors that I get.

Comment: If you use `mysql_connect()` there would be no use in calling `mysql_close()` as its closed at end of execution anyways. What i suggest is use mysqli or PDO as the mysql_* functions are in the deprecation process.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the good news for your client is that the previous developer abandoned the project.  He could only have done more damage if he had continued working on it.

- This script is using ext/mysql, not ext/mysqli.  It would be better to use mysqli or PDO_mysql, since [ext/mysql is deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).
- It's recommended to use the full PHP open tag syntax (`<?php`), not the short-tags syntax (`<?`).    The reason is that not every PHP environment enables the use of short tags, and if you deploy code into such an environment, your code will be viewable by anyone browsing to the page.
- This script does no error checking.  You should always check for errors after attempting to connect to a database or submitting a query.
- The method of using `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1` to choose a random row from a database is well known to be inefficient, and it cannot be optimized.  As the table grows to have more than a trivial number of rows, this query is likely to be your bottleneck.  See some of [my past answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:20860%20[random]) about optimizing ORDER BY RAND queries, or a great [blog by Jan Kneschke](http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/) on selecting random rows.
- Even if you are stuck using `ORDER BY RAND()`, there's no need to call it three times to get three distinct random sponsors.  Just use `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3`.  Then you don't need the complex and error-prone update against bannerRotation to ensure that you get sponsors that haven't been chosen before.
- Using `SELECT *` fetches all the columns, even though they aren't needed for this function.
- If a sponsor isn't eligible for random selection, i.e. if it has active!='Y' or if its ID=999, then I would move it to a different table.  This will simplify your queries, and make the table of sponsors smaller and quicker to query.
- The `UPDATE` in the grab() function has no `WHERE` clause, so it applies to *all* rows in the sponsor table.  I don't believe this is intentional.  I assume it should apply only to the single row `WHERE ID=$banner['ID']`.
- This code has two consecutive `UPDATE` statements against the same row of the same table.  Combine these into a single `UPDATE` statement that modifies two columns.
- The grab() function appends values together separated by commas, and then explodes that string into an array as soon as it returns.  As if the programmer doesn't know that a function can return an array.
- Putting the `$i++` inside a conditional block makes it possible for this code to run in an infinite loop.  That means this script can run forever.  Once a few dozen of these are running concurrently, you'll run out of connections.
- This code uses no caching.  Any script that serves ad banners must be quick, and doing multiple updates to the database is not going to be quick enough.  You need to use some in-memory caching for reads and writes.  A popular choice is [memcached](http://php.net/memcached).

Why is this client coding their own ad-banner server so inexpertly?  Just use [Google DFP Small Business](https://www.google.com/intl/en_US/dfp/info/welcome.html).

Comment: Thank you Bill for the schooling, I appreciate it.  I will work on these changes.  I hate cleaning up someone elses mess.

Comment: I feel your pain.  We've all been there.

Answer (score 0):

Yikes!

`grab()` is being called from within a loop, but is not parameterized.  Nor does there seem to be any rationale for repeatedly calling it.

A 200% speedup is easily realizable.

Comment: Yeah, this was built by another web developer who abandoned the cusgtomer and now I am trying to clean it up and make it work.  You can see the site at webrodder.com.  The rotating ads were working, but are not now.  Anyone have a simple fix for this?